# programatically get the file size from a remote file using delphi, before download it

Tags: delphi

How i can determine the size in bytes of a remote file hosted in the web, before download it, using Delphi?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: How are you planing to download it http/ftp etc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use Indy.

First include `IdHTTP`.

You can retrieve the size this way:

```
procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Http.Head('http://live.sysinternals.com/ADExplorer.exe');

    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Http.Response.ContentLength));
  finally
    Http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: use the HTTP HEAD command, available in the TIdHttp component of Indy Delphi.

Details:

HTTP protocol defines a `HEAD` method.

> **9.4 HEAD**
>
> The HEAD method is identical to GET
>   except that the server MUST NOT return
>   a message-body in the response. The
>   metainformation contained in the HTTP
>   headers in response to a HEAD request
>   SHOULD be identical to the information
>   sent in response to a GET request.
>   This method can be used for obtaining
>   metainformation about the entity
>   implied by the request without
>   transferring the entity-body itself.
>   This method is often used for testing
>   hypertext links for validity,
>   accessibility, and recent
>   modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be
>   cacheable in the sense that the
>   information contained in the response
>   MAY be used to update a previously
>   cached entity from that resource. If
>   the new field values indicate that the
>   cached entity differs from the current
>   entity (as would be indicated by a
>   change in Content-Length, Content-MD5,
>   ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache
>   MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

HEAD Asks for the response identical to the one that would correspond to a GET request, but without the response body, retrieving the complete response headers, without the entire content.

The HTTP response headers retrieved are documented in *List of HTTP headers* on Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

> HTTP Headers form the core of an HTTP request, 
>   and are very important in an HTTP response. 
>   They define various characteristics of the data 
>   that is requested or the data that has been provided. 
>   The headers are separated from the request or 
>   response body by a blank line. HTTP headers 
>   can be near-arbitrary strings, but only some 
>   are commonly understood.

One of the headers that is always present for a valid URL to retrieve a content is 
the `Content-Length` header.

> **14.13 Content-Length**
>
> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the 
>   size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, 
>   sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, 
>   the size of the entity-body that would have been sent 
>   had the request been a GET.
>
> `Content-Length    = "Content-Length" ":" 1*DIGIT`
>
> An example is
>
> `Content-Length: 3495`
>
> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the 
>   transfer-length of the message-body, unless this is 
>   prohibited by the rules in section 4.4.
>
> Any Content-Length greater than or equal to zero is a 
>   valid value. Section 4.4 describes  how to determine 
>   the length of a message-body if a Content-Length is not given.
>
> Note that the meaning of this field is significantly 
>   different from the corresponding definition in MIME, 
>   where it is an optional field used within the 
>   "message/external-body" content-type. In HTTP, 
>   it SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length 
>   can be determined prior to being transferred, 
>   unless this is prohibited by the rules in section 4.4.

From Delphi, drop a TIdHttp component to your form. And paste the following code in one of your delphi event process methods.

```
var 
  url: string;  // must contain a fully qualified url
  contentLength: integer;
begin
  ....
  contentLength:=0;
  try
    Idhttp1.Head(url);
    contentLength:=idhttp1.response.ContentLength;
  except end;
  ....
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that not ALL servers will return a valid content size for a head request.  If the content length = 0, then you will ONLY know if you issue a GET request. For example the HEAD request against the [Google logo](http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif) returns a 0 content-length, however a GET returns the proper length, but also retrieves the image.  Some servers will return content-length as the length of the packet following the header.

You can use [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) to get at this information also.  Note that the data is transfered, but the buffer is thrown away.  This is a much more reliable method, but at the cost of additional bandwidth.

```
var
  HTTP : tHTTPSend;
begin
  HTTP := THTTPSend.Create;
  try
    HTTP.HTTPMethod('GET',url);
    DownloadSize := HTTP.DownloadSize;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's really two answers. First part is useful, there are some web servers that have this misbehavior, although this is a (another) violation of the HTTP protocol definition. (2) Second part is not useful, the question was "how to determine the size **before** downloading"; so downloading the data is not a valid alternative here.

Comment: It is not really misbehavior.  Some servers don't deliver data in a single byte stream, such as for dynamically-generated data.  In those situations (ie: when the "Transfer-Encoding" header includes "chunked"), the data size is simply not known ahead of time.

Comment: @Remy: Right, in some circumstances like dynamic streaming, and 'chunked' encoding this behavior is correct. **But** the google logo example is unobjectionably (is this an english word?) a misbehavior.