# Check if a file exists on a remote server using Delphi

Tags: http, delphi

I need to check if a file exists on a server using delphi..
The idea is to send a request to the server (ex : http://www.example.com/file.txt) and check the status code of the response..
how is it done in delphi?

Comment: Check answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2184015/11480), in your case, use `HEAD` request and check the response status code, it should be either 200 - OK, 3xx - redirect or 4xx error. See [HTTP 1.1 status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: You can't truly check if a file exist on a remote server using the HTTP protocol, you can only check if a URL is valid or not. If the file exists but the server doesn't want to serve it, it might return a `403` status code, or `500`, even `404` is possible. On the flip size, just because a web server returns status code `200`, it doesn't really mean there's a file with the given name! Your test only works if you know how the HTTP server is configured!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **TIdHTTP** class (included in Delphi). Simply create an instance at run time and use its **Head** method to retrieve information about the server resource.

```
MyIdHTTP.Head(TheURL);
ResponseCode :=  MyIdHTTP.Response.ResponseCode; // 200 = OK etc
ContentLength := MyIdHTTP.Response.ContentLength;
```

Note that it will not download the whole resource, and the value in ContentLength is not guaranteed ok (for example for dynamically created resources)

Comment: Beware that in some odd cases, this can take a very very long time.  I recommend putting all such could-potentially-fail-while-taking-30-to-60-second items in a background thread.    I also recommend you specify a timeout explicitly in each case when you do an Http head request rather than leaving the defaults.  It makes the fact that the operation can take a long time more explicit and clear in your code.

Answer (score 1):

**hyper(abstract)** text transfer protocol.
you can use ftp protocol for this purpose

Comment: This should be comment.